# WCF service doesn't accept new member to the enum

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got a wcf service which looked something like this:

```
[DataContract]
enum MyEnum
{
    [EnumMember]Member1,
    [EnumMember]Member2,        
    [EnumMember]Member3
}


[ServiceContract]
interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SolveBotguard(
        SolutionType myEnum);
}
```

The service worked fine, and I've created a working client with a mex endpoint that it exposed.

Now I added a new member to the enum:

```
[DataContract]
enum MyEnum
{
    [EnumMember]Member1,
    [EnumMember]Member2,        
    [EnumMember]Member4,  
    [EnumMember]Member3
}
```

And again, updated the client through MEX endpoint. But now, when I'm trying to call the service with the new enum member as param, I'm getting following error:

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There 
was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:myEnum. 
The InnerException message was 'Invalid enum value 'Member4' cannot be 
deserialized into type 'MyEnum'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are  
present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has
DataContractAttribute attribute.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

I've tried deleting client and service files and re-building them from the source, with no effect.

How do I get rid of this exception?

Comment: check if the enum value appears in the service WSDL (or one of its referenced XSD files) and also if it appears in the generated proxy. Also do some otehr change in the server (rename some method) and see if the client is updated with that change.

Comment: Are you sure you updated the client against your local development mex endpoint and not some downstream environment endpoint (which has yet to be updated with latest code)?

Comment: if i didn't update it, it wouldn't let me call method with the new enum value

Comment: Have you published your service? I guess it might be the reason. Because even if you get the old service reference you can call the method with your new enum value since it exists in your solution and it might use the `enum` that you've created, not of the services.

Answer (score -1):

Probably too late to answer this but try and rebuild your client (choose the menu option) application.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is years late, but it might help someone else with the same issue. In my case, the problem was that I simply didn't have the latest version of the code. Get latest version, rebuild and try again.

Here is some background on how I figured out the solution to my problem:
Apparently, I had the latest version of the service side code, but had old UI code. The service call originates from the UI so I tried debugging the UI part of our app. When I tried debugging the related viewmodel, Visual Studio told me that the breakpoint will never be hit because the source code didn't match. At that point it was easy. I started from scratch, deleted all my files, got latest version from TFS, did a rebuild and the problem was solved.